# Is this the correct way to get file's size?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, filesize, fileinfo

I have retrieved all file names and store it to a string array. Following is the code:

```
Dim fi As System.IO.FileInfo
Dim file_size As Int32
'all file names are stored in Files string array
Dim Files() As String
Dim CurrentFile As String

For Each CurrentFile In Files
    fi = New System.IO.FileInfo(CurrentFile)
    file_size = fi.Length
Next
```

Is this the correct way of getting each file's size? Is there any better way to get file size? I have thousand of files and I'm looking for a better approach.

Comment: Yes, you need to use `FileInfo` to get such info

Comment: What is the question? MSDN perfectly says that "FileInfo.Length Property 
 - Gets the size, in bytes, of the current file.

"

Comment: @sll: Initially I think, to create a new FileInfo for each file just to retrieve its size seemed wasteful. So ask if there is better way to get each file size

Comment: It is ok to use FileInfo. But it is rather confusing to use 'Files' in your example - use please one fileName to keep your example simple.

Comment: I'd try it first on both ANSI and UNICODE files, to be sure about double byte files. The size in bytes is not the size for unicode, you know. If I had Studio on this pc would have tried it myself.

Comment: File content doesn't matter. The size is always in bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the FileInfo classes Length Property gives you the size of the file in bytes.

[FileInfo Description MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx)